# How to select an element (like a pop-up box) showing after a click with puppeteer and mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, puppeteer

I'm working with mocha test and I'd like to test if an element is visible after click button. One similar situation is when you click "like" button on youtube without sign-in.

Any suggestions?

I tried to use the following code to select the dom, but it always get "undefinded", while I can select it from the browser.

await page.waitFor(3000);

await page.$('#contentWrapper > ytd-modal-with-title-and-button-renderer')

Answer (score 1):

**You can use following:**

```
await page.waitForNavigation();
await page.waitForSelector('#contentWrapper > ytd-modal-with-title-and-button-renderer', {visible: true});
```

`waitForNavigation` - will wait for new page to load(if there is a page load going on)

`waitForSelector` - method will wait for particular selector to appear in a dom

`{visible: true}` - will make sure element is visible

If it doesn't work, that means there is no page load going on and you can simply delete first line and run this:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#contentWrapper > ytd-modal-with-title-and-button-renderer', {visible: true});
```

And here is an extra one in case you will use [xpath](https://qalesson.com/ui/2018/01/11/The-Power-Of-Xpath.html) in the future:

```
await page.waitForXPath( xpath_selector );
```

It's a same one as `waitForSelector` but for xpath usage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `waitForSelector`. It can wait for page change and fire only when this selector appear in the page.

[Here documentation about this.](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)